# SSIS connection issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have a problem running SSIS package from my local machine which is due to connection issue as I get  this error message '
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "xxxxx". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.'

I have always created and run SSIS packages on the remote server. For some reason, now I get an error 'Object reference not set correctly...' error message. I should reinstall Visual Studio 2008 and that should mostly solve the problem. But doing this needs lot of permission etc so meanwhile I am trying to execute the package from my local machine by mapping the package folder to my PC.

My computer's windows login id is something like '**ABC\SK**' while remote server log in id is like '**ABC\HA-SK**'. 
**ABC\SK** is not an authorized user on the remote desktop or the SQL server.

I am only able to execute packages that do file system operations like moving, renaming files etc but not execute any SQL statement. For that matter, I cannot create a OLEDB connection as well in a new package.

How to get around this access issues? What are my options? Is the option to give sufficient privilages to  **ABC\SK**? But the corporate policy won't allow it.

Appreciate any help. Thank You very much.

--SK

Comment: Can you login to the SQL Server from your local computer? Are you using windows/trusted/SSPI authentication?

Comment: Normally you would run your package against a development version of the database, and then there would be no issues giving a developer access.

Comment: Hi ElectricLama, Yes, I am able to login to the SQL server from my local computer. With respect to SSIS packages, I can't connect to the SQL server from ssis pacakages. I tried 'Run as different user' and gave credentials of my remote desktop windows id which is the authentication valid on he SQL server as well. But I can't see the mapped drive from open->Project from VS BIDS.

Comment: DO not use mapped drives. Use UNC's. When you create an OLEDB connection in  a new package, does it work right up until you test the connection details or does it fail before that? (i.e. when you drop the connection on). You aren't using ODBC are you?

Comment: @ElectricLlama, Yes, I had to use UNC to locate the files and it worked like a charm! I realized I need to think in terms of who I am when I am working with different accounts etc. For the benefit of anyone ever looking up solution for this kind of problem here is what I did:                                                             1. Open SSIS 'Run as different user'.Log in 'HA-SK'credentials.(Ctrl+Shit +Right click)                                           2. Use UNC path in all file operations.                                   3. Copy SSIS packages under windows users folder 'HA-SK'.

Comment: I put my comment is an answer. If you want me to expand further let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use mapped drives. Use UNC's. When you create an OLEDB connection in a new package, does it work right up until you test the connection details or does it fail before that? (i.e. when you drop the connection on). You aren't using ODBC are you?